# Is there anyway to apply different color for different parameters within the same formula (especially for background presentation)?

Tags: color

The photo is from [Prof Alfredo Canziani from NYU](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiSipat0vL1AhWBX3wKHRy0AGEQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fatcold.github.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw3YjLNDQthX2mE2HefZLuix), who manage to create presentation with formulas which parameters using different colour regarding to a same formula.

I wonder is there any editors or tricks in Latex to achieve this especially for blackground presentation.

[image]

[Link of reference to Professor Alfredo's photo](https://twitter.com/alfcnz/status/1489739194058616832?s=20&t=9eqXR2yzN6IpgUewUcAC-Q)

### What I have tried?

I have tried to use [draw.io](http://draw.io) for this code

```
$$x \text { in }\left(Z_{p}\right)^{*} \text { is a Q.R. } \Leftrightarrow x^{(p-1) / 2}=1 \text { in } Z_{p}$$
```

[image]
[image]
The Latex become uncompilable after only assign colors to a certain parameters in the formula

Comment: What you try so far? At least provide a code of equations ...

Comment: I have added what I have tried, and its code, thanks for advice 

Comment: Based on the other pictures posted, I think the professor was using [manim](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.text.text_mobject.Text.html?highlight=text#textmorecustomization) to generate these LaTeX output that can be manipulated into videos and animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, it may serve as starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
{\color{orange}L}
    \left[ 
{\color{orange}L}({\color{pink}x},{\color{cyan}\mathcal{Y}}),{\color{cyan}y}
    \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You should use editor by which is the most familiar. Some of them enable to define shortcuts.  However on the LaTeX side you can define abbreviations for colored variables. For example, for above MWE is sufficient to define five of them:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand\cF{{\color{orange}F}}
    \newcommand\cL{{\color{orange}L}}
    \newcommand\cx{{\color{pink}x}}
    \newcommand\cy{{\color{cyan}y}}
    \newcommand\cmY{{\color{cyan}\mathcal{Y}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\cL
    \left[
\cF(\cx,\cmY),\cy
    \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is the same as before, but code is significant shorter. Since  the all possible colored variables are unknown to us, is hard to say if this approach is suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any editor do you recommend to assign colors, or we need memorise the grammar? and is there any way to assign main Latex symnbol to white in a given black background environment?

Comment: @Sheldon, you can define new commands as  abbreviations for colored variables. See addendum to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution:

`unicode-math` package calls  `fontspec` package, which has a `[Color=...]` option, at font-level; different colors can be applied to different alphabet ranges.

[image: colours]

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagecolor{black}
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermesMath}[Colour=white]
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermesMath}[range=it/{latin},Colour=cyan]
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermesMath}[range=it/{Latin},Colour=pink]
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermesMath}[range={"0079,"1D466},Colour=brown]%y
\setmathfont{TexGyreTermesMath}[range=cal,Colour=yellow]

\begin{document}
\[
L
    \left[ 
L(x,\mathcal{Y}),y
    \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

In the OP image, the  looks hand-coloured (otherwise `'` would be the same colour, not white). Which means  must be hand-coloured too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any **editors** do you recommend to make it convenient to assign colors to symbols instead of type it by ourselves, or we need memorise the grammar? and is there any way to assign main Latex symnbol to white in a given black background environmen

Comment: @Sheldon I don't understand: do you want the editor to produce the latex code that will make a coloured pdf?

Comment: I am doing presentation with black background which will be good if I can assign the formula parameters in different colors

Comment: @Sheldon Please add a small example of what you have tried so far, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This will help people help you. In particular, do you want the `y` in `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` to be the same colour (because math alphabet), or different colours (because of parameter position)? The colours in the original image are based on math alphabet, not parameter.